# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method

Tags: mysql, xampp

[my log file for latest errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWEME.png)I tried every Method discussed before in similar questions but nothing is working for me. I  tried changing port, deleting all files from mysql/data folder. but nothing is working. Server starts for few seconds and then stops automatically by throwing the above error. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with multi-master file. It can be fixed by deleting all master files in mysql/data folder. That worked for me